# Can one restrict the maximum size of a user database in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I cannot find anything in the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html) about how to restrict users from filling the disks entirely.

We are a small group of people and share a mysql server. I would like to provide every user with a private DB, with all rights to create tables in their private DBs, however they should be prevented from (accidentally) filling the disk of the machine entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to each user its own `TABLESPACE`, to store the tables of the user database in it, and when you create the `TABLESPACE` you can give a maximum size to it.

See the MySQL Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-tablespace.html

Comment: I think it is just for ndb storage engine but not for other like innodb and myisam...